# nltk wordpunct_tokenize vs word_tokenize

Tags: python, nltk

Does anyone know the difference between `nltk`'s `wordpunct_tokenize` and `word_tokenize`? I'm using `nltk=3.2.4` and there's nothing on the doc string of `wordpunct_tokenize` that explains the difference. I couldn't find this info either in the documentation of `nltk` (perhaps I didn't search in the right place!). I would have expected that first one would get rid of punctuation tokens or the like, but it doesn't.

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`wordpunct_tokenize` is based on a simple regexp tokenization. It is defined as

```
wordpunct_tokenize = WordPunctTokenizer().tokenize
```

which you can find [here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.regexp.WordPunctTokenizer). Basically it uses the regular expression `\w+|[^\w\s]+` to split the input.

`word_tokenize` on the other hand is based on a `TreebankWordTokenizer`, see the docs [here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.treebank.TreebankWordTokenizer). It basically tokenizes text like in the Penn Treebank. Here is a silly example that should show how the two differ.

```
sent = "I'm a dog and it's great! You're cool and Sandy's book is big. Don't tell her, you'll regret it! 'Hey', she'll say!"
>>> word_tokenize(sent)
['I', "'m", 'a', 'dog', 'and', 'it', "'s", 'great', '!', 'You', "'re", 
 'cool', 'and', 'Sandy', "'s", 'book', 'is', 'big', '.', 'Do', "n't", 'tell',
 'her', ',', 'you', "'ll", 'regret', 'it', '!', "'Hey", "'", ',', 'she', "'ll", 'say', '!']
>>> wordpunct_tokenize(sent)
['I', "'", 'm', 'a', 'dog', 'and', 'it', "'", 's', 'great', '!', 'You', "'",
 're', 'cool', 'and', 'Sandy', "'", 's', 'book', 'is', 'big', '.', 'Don',
 "'", 't', 'tell', 'her', ',', 'you', "'", 'll', 'regret', 'it', '!', "'", 
 'Hey', "',", 'she', "'", 'll', 'say', '!']
```

As we can see, `wordpunct_tokenize` will split pretty much at all special symbols and treat them as separate units. `word_tokenize` on the other hand keeps things like `'re` together. It doesn't seem to be all that smart though, since as we can see it fails to separate the initial single quote from `'Hey'`.

Interestingly, if we write the sentence like this instead (single quotes as string delimiter and double quotes around "Hey"):

```
sent = 'I\'m a dog and it\'s great! You\'re cool and Sandy\'s book is big. Don\'t tell her, you\'ll regret it! "Hey", she\'ll say!'
```

we get

```
>>> word_tokenize(sent)
['I', "'m", 'a', 'dog', 'and', 'it', "'s", 'great', '!', 'You', "'re", 
 'cool', 'and', 'Sandy', "'s", 'book', 'is', 'big', '.', 'Do', "n't", 
 'tell', 'her', ',', 'you', "'ll", 'regret', 'it', '!', '``', 'Hey', "''", 
 ',', 'she', "'ll", 'say', '!']
```

so `word_tokenize` does split off double quotes, however it also converts them to ``` `` ``` and `''`. `wordpunct_tokenize` doesn't do this:

```
>>> wordpunct_tokenize(sent)
['I', "'", 'm', 'a', 'dog', 'and', 'it', "'", 's', 'great', '!', 'You', "'", 
 're', 'cool', 'and', 'Sandy', "'", 's', 'book', 'is', 'big', '.', 'Don', 
 "'", 't', 'tell', 'her', ',', 'you', "'", 'll', 'regret', 'it', '!', '"', 
 'Hey', '",', 'she', "'", 'll', 'say', '!']
```

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. So to summarize, for NLP cleaning purpose you should always go for word_tokenize because you would not want to handle punctuations separately.