# Python string matching - Find if certain number of words in a list of words exist in a sentence in another list

Tags: python, string, list, string-matching

I have a String and a list defined as below

```
my_string = 'she said he replied'
my_list = ['This is a cool sentence', 'This is another sentence','she said hello he replied goodbye', 'she replied', 'Some more sentences in here', 'et cetera et cetera...']
```

I am trying to check if at least 3 words in `my_string` exists in any of the strings in `my_list`. The approach i'm taking is to split `my_string`, and use `all` to do the matching. However, this only works if all the items in `my_string` exist in a sentence from `my_list`

```
if all(word in item for item in my_list for word in my_string.split()):
    print('we happy')
```

1- How can I make it so the condition is satisfied if at least 3 items of `my_string` are present in the sentence list?

2- Is it possible to match only the first and last word in `my_string` in the same order? i.e "she" and "replied" are present in 'she replied' at index 3 of `my_list`, return True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding part 1, I think this should work, and I would recommend using a regex and  not string.split for finding words.You could also use nltk.word_tokenize if your sentences have complex words and punctuation. They are both slower than string.split, but if you need them, they're useful.

Here's a couple decent posts highlighting the differences (wordpunct-tokenize is basically a word regex in disguise):

[nltk wordpunct_tokenize vs word_tokenize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50240029/nltk-wordpunct-tokenize-vs-word-tokenize)

[Python re.split() vs nltk word_tokenize and sent_tokenize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345761/python-re-split-vs-nltk-word-tokenize-and-sent-tokenize)

```
import re

num_matches = 3

def get_words(input):
    return re.compile('\w+').findall(input)

my_string = 'she said he replied'
my_list = ['This is a cool sentence', 'This is another sentence','she said hello he replied goodbye', 'she replied', 'Some more sentences in here', 'et cetera et cetera...']

my_string_word_set = set(get_words(my_string))
my_list_words_set = [set(get_words(x)) for x in my_list]

result = [len(my_string_word_set.intersection(x)) >= num_matches for x in my_list_words_set]
print(result)
```

Results in

> [False, False, True, False, False, False]

For part 2, something like this should work, though it's not a super clean solution. If you don't want them just in order, but next to each other, check that the indexes are 1 apart instead.

```
words = get_words(my_string)
first_and_last = [words[0], words[-1]]
my_list_dicts = []
for sentence in my_list:
    word_dict = {}
    sentence_words = get_words(sentence)
    for i, word in enumerate(sentence_words):
        word_dict[word] = i
    my_list_dicts.append(word_dict)

result2 = []
for word_dict in my_list_dicts:
    if all(k in word_dict for k in first_and_last) and word_dict[first_and_last[0]] < word_dict[first_and_last[1]]:
        result2.append(True)
    else:
        result2.append(False)

print(result2)
```

Result:

> [False, False, True, True, False, False]

Answer (score 2):

The words in common between two strings can be computed using a set intersection. The `len` of the resulting set gives you the number of words the strings have in common.

First build a set of all words in the strings in `my_list`, using a set union:

```py
all_words = set.union(*[set(item.split()) for item in my_list])
```

Then check if the intersection has length `>= 3`:

```py
search_words = set(my_string.split())
if len(search_words & all_words) >= 3:
    print('we happy')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the inherent coding that `True` is 1, `False` is 0.
Sum the values of the `in` results:

```
if sum(word in item for item in my_list for word in my_string.split()) >= 3:
    print('we happy')
```

For your given input, this prints `we happy`.

Re: `mamun`'s point, we also want to make sure that whole words match.  You'll need to split each string in `my_list` to get the list of available words.  `kaya3` already posted what I would tell you to do.

Comment: it will return True for 'he' in 'another'

Answer (score 1):

you can use flashtext as well for doing this

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor

kw_list = my_string.split()
kp = KeywordProcessor()
kp.add_keywords_from_list(kw_list) # add keyword that you are looking for 

def func_(x):
    kw = kp.extract_keywords(x)  # this will return all keyword present in the string
    return len(set(kw)) # now you find the sum of unique kw found in string 

print(list(map(func_, my_list)))
[0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 0]
```